# error in cdfCompare, object 'discrete' not found

Tags: r, cdf

I was plotting 2 cumulative distribution for 2 columns of data in a dataframe. my code is:

```
library(EnvStats)
cdfCompare(Ratio1,Ratio2 discrete = FALSE, 
           prob.method = ifelse(discrete, "emp.probs", "plot.pos"), plot.pos.con = NULL, 
           distribution = "norm", param.list = NULL, 
           estimate.params = is.null(param.list), est.arg.list = NULL, 
           x.col = "blue", y.or.fitted.col = "black", 
           x.lwd = 3 * par("cex"), y.or.fitted.lwd = 3 * par("cex"), 
           x.lty = 1, y.or.fitted.lty = 2, digits = .Options$digits, 
           type = ifelse(discrete, "s", "l"), main = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, 
           xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL)
```

When I ran this code an error was generated:

```
Error in ifelse(discrete, "emp.probs", "plot.pos") : 
  object 'discrete' not found
```

When I use a shorter code:

```
cdfCompare(Ratio1,Ratio2 discrete = FALSE)
```

There is no error. I also tried to set

> discrete=TRUE

, it looks it does not affect the shape of the plotting (not smooth, I have ~170,000 values). Thank you very much.[image]

Comment: The `ifelse` Is trying to find an object named `discrete`, it can’t be used to test if the function argument  `discrete` Is set to `TRUE` The way you’ve written it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a separate variable to pass discrete value and use `if`/`else` to select `prob.method`.

```
discrete_value <- FALSE

cdfCompare(Ratio1,Ratio2 discrete = discrete_value, 
           prob.method = if(discrete_value) "emp.probs" else "plot.pos", plot.pos.con = NULL, 
           distribution = "norm", param.list = NULL, 
           estimate.params = is.null(param.list), est.arg.list = NULL, 
           x.col = "blue", y.or.fitted.col = "black", 
           x.lwd = 3 * par("cex"), y.or.fitted.lwd = 3 * par("cex"), 
           x.lty = 1, y.or.fitted.lty = 2, digits = .Options$digits, 
           type = ifelse(discrete, "s", "l"), main = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, 
           xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works out. Just  need to change: 
type = ifelse(discrete, "s", "l") to type = ifelse(discrete_value, "s", "l")